# Is there an "Always Encrypted" equivalent encryption implementation/extension available in postgresql which could work with .net core 3.1?

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, encryption, entity-framework-core, always-encrypted

I have checked the implementation of the pgcrypto extension. It doesn't automatically encrypt and decrypt data, using EF Core and requires separate functions.
Whereas, the "Always Encrypted" feature of SQL Server does it transparently without much code change.

So is there anything like this available in PostgreSQL as well?

Comment: You could look at [Microsoft SQL Server 2019 to Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL Migration Playbook - Column Encryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sql-server-to-aurora-postgresql-migration-playbook/chap-sql-server-aurora-pg.security.columnencryption.html). It describes a scenario that look a bit like Always Encrypted, but is not as transparent.